# Stack dataframes in Pandas vertically and horizontally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  country region  region_id  year  doy  variable_a  num_pixels
0     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    1        32.2         100
1     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    2        12.2         100
2     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    3        22.2         100
3     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    4       112.2         100
4     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    5        52.2         100
```

The year in the dataframe above is 2022. I have more dataframes for other years starting from 2010 onwards.
I have also dataframes for other variables: `variable_b`, `variable_c`.

I want to combine all these dataframes into a single dataframe such that

1. The years are listed vertically, one below the other
2. the data for the different variables is listed horizontally. The output should look like this:

```
  country region  region_id  year  doy  variable_a  variable_b  variable_c
0     USA   Iowa      12345  2010    1        32.2          44         101
1     USA   Iowa      12345  2010    2        12.2          76        2332
..........................................................................
n-1   USA   Iowa      12345  2022    1       321.2         444         501
n     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    2       122.2         756          32
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?
Please note that there will be overlap in years in the other dataframes so the solution needs to take that into account and not leave NaN values.

Comment: Is it ok if I combine all methods into one answer and show their timings? so it accounts efficiency

Comment: What part of René's answer doesn't work? I see you haven't replied to them or given any feedback at all...

Comment: "The solution does not work if the years are overlapping in df1, df2 and df3" Please explain more, we do not how you want to order your dataframes

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible set of input DataFrames and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure people are hearing the second parts of your question:

> the data for the different variables is listed horizontally.

and

> there will be overlap in years in the other dataframes so the solution needs to take that into account and not leave NaN values.

I think I understand, and this is my solution.

We start by creating a baby dataset of two years, five days each, with two variables.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Baseline dummy data
data = {
    'country': {0: 'USA', 1: 'USA', 2: 'USA', 3: 'USA', 4: 'USA'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowa', 1: ' Iowa', 2: ' Iowa', 3: ' Iowa', 4: ' Iowa'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2022, 1: 2022, 2: 2022, 3: 2022, 4: 2022},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

# 2022 data with "a" data
df_2022_a = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_2022_a["variable_a"] = range(5)

# 2022 data with "b" data
df_2022_b = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_2022_b["variable_b"] = range(5, 10)

# 2021 data with "a" data
df_2021_a = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_2021_a["variable_a"] = range(10, 15)
df_2021_a["year"] = 2021

# 2021 data with "b" data
df_2021_b = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_2021_b["variable_b"] = range(15, 20)
df_2021_b["year"] = 2021

frames = [df_2022_a, df_2022_b, df_2021_a, df_2021_b]

# Get the columns that they all share. This is what we'll group by.
# You can hard-code this if you want
common_cols = list(set.intersection(*(set(df.columns) for df in frames)))

# Yes, go ahead and concatenate them together... but there's one more step!
df = pd.concat(frames)
df
```

[image]

Here, you're left with a lot of **duplicate days** and a lot of `NaN`s. Collapse your dataframe by doing something like the following:

```py
output_df = (
    df
    .groupby(by=common_cols)  # Only keep distinct values for the common cols
    .max()                    # Max will prefer non-nan values over nans
    .reset_index()            # Collapse the multi-index
    .sort_values(common_cols) # Sort by all these to get it nice and orderly
    .reset_index(drop=True)   # Tidy up the dataframe index
)
output_df
```

[image]

I believe this is the type of output that OP is asking for.

As for there being no `NaN`s in the final product, that'll *really* depend on the data coverage over all variable for all years and days.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
data1 = {
    'country': {0: 'USA', 1: 'USA', 2: 'USA', 3: 'USA', 4: 'USA'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowa', 1: ' Iowa', 2: ' Iowa', 3: ' Iowa', 4: ' Iowa'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2022, 1: 2022, 2: 2022, 3: 2022, 4: 2022},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'variable_a': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

data2 = {
    'country': {0: 'USB', 1: 'USB', 2: 'USB', 3: 'USB', 4: 'USB'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowb', 1: ' Iowb', 2: ' Iowb', 3: ' Iowb', 4: ' Iowb'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2021, 1: 2021, 2: 2021, 3: 2021, 4: 2021},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'variable_b': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

data3 = {
    'country': {0: 'USC', 1: 'USC', 2: 'USC', 3: 'USC', 4: 'USC'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowc', 1: ' Iowc', 2: ' Iowc', 3: ' Iowc', 4: ' Iowc'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2020, 1: 2020, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2020},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'variable_c1': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'variable_c2': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

dfn = [df1, df2, df3]

pd.concat(dfn, axis=0).sort_values(['year', 'country', 'region']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The dates are not according to the format the user asked for. Rows with the year 2021 should be displayed first.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat` method to do this efficiently. The method does the work by listing all the data frames in vertical order and also creates new columns for all the new variables.

Here is an example of how `pd.concat` works I created with duplicate data.

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"country": ["USA", "USA", "USA"], "region": ["Iowa", "Iowa", "Iowa"],
                    "region_id": [12345, 12345, 12345], "year": [2022, 2022, 2022], "doy": [1, 2, 3],
                    "variable_a": [32.2, 12.2, 22.2], "num_pixles": [100, 100, 100]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"country": ["USA", "USA", "USA"], "region": ["Iowa", "Iowa", "Iowa"],
                    "region_id": [12345, 12345, 12345], "year": [2020, 2020, 2020], "doy": [1, 2, 3],
                    "variable_b": [54.2, 62.2, 2.2], "num_pixles": [100, 100, 100]})

df_list = [df1, df2]  # list of dataframes

res = pd.concat(df_list) # concat the list of dataframes
res = res.sort_values(by="year").reset_index(drop=True)  # To make sure that the rows are sorted based on year
print(res)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
      country region  region_id  year  doy  variable_a  num_pixles  variable_b
0     USA   Iowa      12345  2020    1         NaN         100        54.2
1     USA   Iowa      12345  2020    2         NaN         100        62.2
2     USA   Iowa      12345  2020    3         NaN         100         2.2
3     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    1        32.2         100         NaN
4     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    2        12.2         100         NaN
5     USA   Iowa      12345  2022    3        22.2         100         NaN
```

Comment: I suppose the guy with 19K reputation and top tags python and pandas should know about `pd.concat`. Maybe the problem is somewhat deeper than that.

Comment: @Vitalizzare It's all about efficiency in this case

Answer (score 0):

## All methods

#### @René

```
res = pd.concat(dfn, axis=0).sort_values(['year', 'country', 'region']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Timing (average of 1000 runs):

```
0.003601184606552124
```

---

#### @vignesh kanakavalli

```
res = pd.concat(df_list)
res = res.sort_values(by="year").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Timing (average of 1000 runs):

```
0.002223911762237549
```

---

#### @DialFrost

```
def fast_flatten(input_list, df):
  r = list(chain.from_iterable(input_list))
  r += [np.nan] * (len(df.index)*3 - len(r))
  return list(r)

def combine_lists(frames):
  COLUMN_NAMES = [frames[i].columns for i in range(len(frames))]
  COL_NAMES = list(set(list(chain(*COLUMN_NAMES))))
  df_dict = dict.fromkeys(COL_NAMES, [])
  for col in COL_NAMES:
    extracted = (frame[col] for frame in frames if col in frame.columns.tolist())
    df_dict[col] = fast_flatten(extracted, dfn[0])
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)[COL_NAMES]

res = combine_lists(dfn)
res = res.sort_values(by = "year").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Timing (1000 runs):

```
0.0021250741481781007
```

*Explanation of my code*:

Here I used a trick. Instead of using `pd.concat`, I decided to go for appending. *Especially* for larger dataframes, **use the appending** method found on github [here](https://gist.github.com/TariqAHassan/fc77c00efef4897241f49e61ddbede9e?permalink_comment_id=3524099#gistcomment-3524099) - (I used a slightly modified version of the code). This one is slightly large enough to beat `pd.concat` and wins in efficiency.

---

*All tests use the same dataframe*:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'country': {0: 'USA', 1: 'USA', 2: 'USA', 3: 'USA', 4: 'USA'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowa', 1: ' Iowa', 2: ' Iowa', 3: ' Iowa', 4: ' Iowa'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2022, 1: 2022, 2: 2022, 3: 2022, 4: 2022},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'variable_a': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

data2 = {
    'country': {0: 'USB', 1: 'USB', 2: 'USB', 3: 'USB', 4: 'USB'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowb', 1: ' Iowb', 2: ' Iowb', 3: ' Iowb', 4: ' Iowb'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2021, 1: 2021, 2: 2021, 3: 2021, 4: 2021},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'variable_b': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

data3 = {
    'country': {0: 'USC', 1: 'USC', 2: 'USC', 3: 'USC', 4: 'USC'},
    'region': {0: ' Iowc', 1: ' Iowc', 2: ' Iowc', 3: ' Iowc', 4: ' Iowc'},
    'region_id': {0: 12345, 1: 12345, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
    'year': {0: 2020, 1: 2020, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2020},
    'doy': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'variable_c1': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'variable_c2': {0: 32.2, 1: 12.2, 2: 22.2, 3: 112.2, 4: 52.2},
    'num_pixels': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100}
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

dfn = [df1, df2, df3]
```

---

*All tests used this timing control*:

```
for x in range(1000):
  start = time.time()
  .
  .
  .
  end = time.time()
  lst.append(end-start)
print(sum(lst)/len(lst))
print(res)
```